# Laravel Eloquent not inserting Model Properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `Friends` table in the database. It has the following field: `id` and `name`.

I have a `Friend` Class in the Models folder:

```
class Friend extends Eloquent {

public $username;

}
```

When I go to insert a new `Friend` an entry is placed into the table; however, the `username` in the database is always blank.

```
$friend = new Friend;
$friend->username = 'Monster';
$friend->save();
return $friend->username;
```

I return the `$username` and lo-and-behold it is **Monster**; however, the database shows a blank username.

EDIT: also, when I update an entry:

```
$friend = Friend::find(1);
$friend->username = "My new name";
$friend->save();
```

Not only is the `username` not updated, but neither is the `updated timestamp.

Comment: Try extending the class by `Model` and do this in ur model class `protected $table = 'Friends ';`

Comment: Instead of extending by `Eloquent`?

Comment: Causes an error: nothing is inserted into the database.

Comment: In laravel 4 the eloquent class should be extended from `Eloquent` . `Model` is for laravel 5 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write your attributes like this because attributes are accessing with magic method. Remove this line `public $username;` from your model.

You can see how it all works [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3010).

Comment: Bingo. But... I'm a bit confused: I thought I had to specify the properties of the object? In addition, what if I wanted to do some specific validation?

Comment: Absolutely not, the base model have an array (e.g. "attributes") where the attributes are stored. Then when you do something `$friend->username` Laravel go fetch this attribute in the array.

Comment: Ah ok. How can additional validation be performed?

Comment: Additional validation? I think you should take a look at the mutator and accessor section from the doc http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators